# SSRS - Display a tablix across a single page

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am using Report Builder 3 to create a simple report. My report is formatted to be printed in Landscape mode on letter sized paper. 
I have a single 3 column tablix, that returns about 100 results from a dataset. Instead of breaking to a new page, I want the data to continue displaying in a new set of columns across the page, so that it all fits on a single page. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

add three tablix on the one page then divided the data on it..

Comment: That's the part I'm not sure how to do. How do you get the other two tablix to be repeating grids for the first one.

Comment: drag and drop tablix  from the toolbox in SSMS project in BIDS. How are you developing your report?

Comment: I am developing it in MS Report Builder 3.0

Comment: I use Buss Iinteligent Deveplment Studio.  I am sure that you can do this. simply copy and paste the tablix object.